# Trouble launching react-native on physical iOS device (9.3)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Only using the react-native-cli starter without changing any app code, I've done everything possible to launch on physical device.

I've followed the react-native docs, changed the IP address to my mac's, provisioned my phone, everything. Please help, as I've spent hours on this.

It seems the react-native0.29 AppDelegate file is different than 0.21. Could this be problem?

Here's the error screenshot:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmFAk.png)

Comment: Are both devices on the same WIFI network? If so then quit the mac Terminal and build the app when your phone is connected to your mac. when it says "Graph ready", hit the Run button to run it on your phone.

Comment: @meteorite, both are connected to same WIFI

Comment: Then please follow the steps I mentioned in the previous comment. Usually quitting the Terminal and building + running the app solves the problem but sometimes it needs to be repeated a few times.

Comment: Also please remember that you have to set the local IP of your computer. the IP that appears on the error page does not seem to be a local IP.

Comment: Quit and built again three times. Still no luck. Does it have to do with new AppDelegate file?

Comment: Changed the IP to another WIFI, which results in local 192 address and still no luck.

Comment: I noticed that the AppDelegate is different in 0.29 also. Try reverting that file

Comment: Reverted the file to 0.21 version. No change.

Comment: Open Safari Browser on your phone and try to open the bundle URL that appears on the error page. If you cant open it it means that you have a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out:

```
[[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] setDefaults];
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

and add

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipaddressofmachine:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

Also try restarting the physical device

Clearing watchman if using it `watchman watch-del-all`

Clear packager temp `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-packager-*`

Quit everything and restart your computer